# Swagger ui is not getting loaded with Oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, swagger-ui, oauth-2.0

I have developed one demo application with spring boot and oauth2. I have three applications as below.

1. Resource api: This will have all the method that we need to secure.
2. Authentication server: This is a oauth2 server that provides the tokens
3. UI: which will be able to access resources after successfully login via Authentication server.

I have few resources (controllers) that can be accessed publicly. But when I am trying to access the swagger ui it asks me for the full authentication. When I added the below code the swagger page is coming but not only one dropdown in whole page and that is also broken.

```
http
.anonymous() //allow anonymous access
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/shouldbepublic/**", "/swagger-ui**/**").permitAll().and() //this should be public resources
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
.and()
.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
.and()
.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Comment: Are you using springfox-swagger-ui as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a configuration which works for me:

`.antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html","/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()'.antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html","/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()`

without that the swagger-ui.html cannot be displayed

The complete `ResourceServiceConfiguration` can be found here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public static class ResourceServiceConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
    // This is needed to enable swagger-ui interface.
    .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html","/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
    // @formatter:on
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if it is safe for you) is to have Spring Security completely ignore the `/swagger-ui` path.

In your security `@Configuration` file extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and add the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/swagger-ui/**");
    super.configure(web);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, I will try and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swagger2 try permitting:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/configuration/**","/swagger**","/webjars/**","/v2/**").permitAll();
```

to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with Spring Security 5 and OAuth2 and Spring Actuator and Swagger/Swagger-UI I had to override Spring Security with this class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/actuator/**",
                    "/v2/api-docs/**",
                    "/swagger-ui.html",
                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                    "/webjars/**"
                )
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
        ;
    }

}
```